# iframes (custom tabs) are not showing up for certain users on business pages, work fine for others

Tags: facebook, iframe

there-- For some reason, a couple of my co-workers and some clients have had problems viewing custom tabs, but not everyone. They work fine for me, and for others in my office.

I've tried a number of things. I've tried having them use the business page both themselves and the business; they can view the raw iframe itself (Page Tab URL) without issue; I've had them try different operating systems and browsers.

These are just straight HTML/CSS/PHP custom tabs, nothing super fancy with Like buttons, etc. Here's a screenshot of what their seeing:

http://cl.jasonandreoni.com/image/3t3P3O3l2141

And a bit of my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
  }, 250);
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion - there is a user setting in facebook to use always https. 
So if your server doesn't have proper SSL certificate / or you have provided wrong secure url in app settings, the tab could not be loaded in https, and only users with that setting on could have the problem.

Comment: Forgot to mention that in my original post, but we are indeed using SSL on our server (and isn't set to expire until May, 2013), and I had my coworker who was experiencing the problem check to make sure they were using FB secure browsing, which she was. And I double checked all of my app settings (300+), and they are all using HTTPS. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas on this? Still having the problem.